# sed/awk: Matching pattern on every 2-lines and aggregate to one line result

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Let's set if I have this data, which comes from `ip addr | grep ether -B1`.

```
11: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 500
    link/ether fe:54:4c:8e:df:f0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
12: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 500
    link/ether fe:54:7a:d0:1a:04 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
13: vnet2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 500
    link/ether fe:54:00:29:ef:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
14: vnet3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 500
    link/ether fe:54:be:c6:c3:32 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
15: vnet4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 500
    link/ether fe:54:e8:cf:ff:ef brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

And I want to summarize it to the form of `<interface> <hwaddr>`:

```
vnet0 fe:54:4c:8e:df:f0
vnet1 fe:54:7a:d0:1a:04
vnet2 fe:54:00:29:ef:0c
vnet3 fe:54:be:c6:c3:32
vnet4 fe:54:e8:cf:ff:ef
```

Can I achieve this by using single bash command with `sed` or `awk`? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through awk,

```
$ awk '/^[0-9]+: +/{split($2,a,":");var=a[1];next}{print var,$2}' file
vnet0 fe:54:4c:8e:df:f0
vnet1 fe:54:7a:d0:1a:04
vnet2 fe:54:00:29:ef:0c
vnet3 fe:54:be:c6:c3:32
vnet4 fe:54:e8:cf:ff:ef
```

**Explanation:**

- `/^[0-9]+: +/` If a line starts with one or more digits followed by a colon plus one or more spaces then execute the codes which are present in the block `{}`

  - `split($2,a,":");` Split the value of column 2 according to the delimiter `:` and then store it into an associative array `a`
  - `var=a[1];` store the value of array index 1 to the variable `var`. That is , it would store the `vnet\d+` into the variable `var`
  - `next` The next statement forces awk to immediately stop processing the current record and go on to the next record. This means that no further rules are executed for the current record, and the rest of the current rule’s action isn’t executed.
- `{print var,$2}` Prints the value stored in the variable `var` plus the next line's column 2 value.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works as expected. And the explanation is very intuitive as well.

Answer (score 1):

A simple awk script can do the purpose.

```
awk '$2~/vnet[0-4]/{inter=$2; next} {print inter,$2}' inputFile
```

will produe output as

```
vnet0: fe:54:4c:8e:df:f0
vnet1: fe:54:7a:d0:1a:04
vnet2: fe:54:00:29:ef:0c
vnet3: fe:54:be:c6:c3:32
vnet4: fe:54:e8:cf:ff:ef
```

What it does?

`$2~/vnet[0-4]/` checks if the second column `$2` mathces the pattern `vnet[0-4]`, if so

`inter=$2; next` assigns the interface to `inter` variable and `next` causes the awk to read the next record without considering the remaining actions.

`print inter,$2` prints interface and hwaddr

Comment: Thank you so much. This works as expected! But the answer from Raj is a little bit more general (I'm not just looking for `vnet[0-4]`, so I toggle it as acceptance.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'N;s/\S+\s+(\S+):.*(..:..:..:..:..:..) .*/\1 \2/' file
```

Read two lines at a time and use pattern matching/back references to extract the required data.

Comment: Cool answer! Thanks a lot. This is what I looking for! Now I know `N` for next line in GNU sed.